# Relacion muchos a uno apiFirst

Tags: api, spring-boot

Trabajo con API first y necesito montar una relacion manytoone. Se que en el DTO debe ir un JsonIgnore en la lista para evitar la recursividad infinita, pero no se configurar el archivo YML que me genera los DTO. este es el codigo de la tabla

```
Equivalencia:
      type: object
      description: Detail for SII Equivalencia.
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          description: Identifier of the Equivalencia
          example: 18
        idTipoEquivalencia:
          type: object
          description: Objeto tipo Equivalencia muchos a uno
        valor:
          type: boolean
          description: valor de la equivalencia (verdadero o falso)
          example: true
        codigo:
          type: string
          description: codigo de equivalencia
          example: "HR"
        descripcion:
          type: string
          description: descripcion de la equivalencia
          example: "El NIF tiene un formato erróneo."

TipoEquivalencia:
      type: object
      description: TipoEquivalencia.
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          description: Identifier of the TipoEquivalencia
          example: 3 
        listaEquivalencia:
          type: array
          description: relacion muchos a uno
        descripcion:
          type: string
          description: Description of the TipoEquivalencia
          example: "tipo_impositivo_recargo"
```

Esta seria el modelo basado en la tabla de BD

```
@Id
    @Column(name = "ID_TIPO_EQUIVALENCIA_SII")
    private long id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "equivalencia")
    private List<Equivalencia> listaEquivalencia;
    
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPCION")
    private String descripcion;
```